# Swift override class func

Tags: ios, class, swift, static

It is easy to override a method in Swift:

```
class A {
   func innerValue() -> Int { return 5 }
   func getInnerValue() -> Int { return innerValue() }
}

class B: A {
   override func innerValue() -> Int { return 8 }
}

B().getInnerValue() //returns 8
```

However I don't know how to do the same when I declare `innerValue()` as *static* (using the `class` keyword):

```
class A {
   class func innerValue() -> Int { return 5 }
   func getInnerValue() -> Int {
      return A.innerValue() //ok for compiler but returns 5 instead of 8
      return self.innerValue() //error: 'A' doesn't have a member named 'innerValue'
      return innerValue() //error: Use of unresolved identifier 'innerValue'
   }
}

class B: A {
   override class func innerValue() -> Int { return 8 }
}

B().getInnerValue()
```

So is it possible in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return A.innerValue() //ok for compiler but returns 5 instead of 8
```

From your comment, it sounds like what you want to do is refer the current instance's class polymorphically. If that's what you want, then don't send the `innerValue()` message to `A`; that means `A` only. And don't send it to `self`, because the way you've written this, `getInnerValue` is an instance method, while what you want to call is a class method. Send it to `self.dynamicType`, the class of the current instance.

Comment: And see the discussion in my Swift book on this topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_reference

Comment: Note that if `getInnerValue` were a class method, `self` would be the right target.

Comment: In Swift 3, `self.dynamicType` has become `type(of: self)`.